# how to change font family of sweetalert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

How can I change the font family in sweetalert? Thank You

```
swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "Your will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            cancelButtonText: "No, cancel plx!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            closeOnCancel: false
        },
```

Comment: Change the CSS rule for the alert.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add this to the css!

```css
.swal2-popup {
  font-size: 1.6rem !important;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer, its just to add the style for the same class

Answer (score 9):

Configuration options are listed [here](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#configuration). They do not appear to include an option for changing the font.

However, all of the elements involved in the SweetAlert popup have SweetAlert-specific classes so you should be able to set the fonts via CSS. Some key classes and examples are listed in the SweetAlert docs under [Theming](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#theming).

Answer (score 1):

For sweetalret2 Add this code to you css file
First one is for main title and the other for subtitle

```
      h2#swal2-title
      {
         font-size: 24px;
         font-family:'Lexend';
         color:theme('colors.metal');
      }
      div#swal2-html-container{
         font-size: 16px;
         font-family:'Heebo';
         color: theme('colors.metal');
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could actually do it by targeting `.swal2-title`, so in css

```js
.swal2-title {
  font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```